# Restore windows 8 boot from ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8

I am trying to restore windows 8 boot from ubuntu since I don't have and recovery CD for windows 8.

I found this guide:
http://robert.penz.name/221/mini-howto-restore-windows-mbrbootloader-with-linux/

but I am not really sure which drive I should install the boot on. This is what I get from `sudo fdisk -l`

```
...
Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 32F9688F-8F84-46A9-93D9-188BF073AA26

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         34    262177    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2     264192    878591    614400   300M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda3     878592   1083391    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda4    1083392 457779199 456695808 217.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  457779200 459732991   1953792   954M Linux swap
/dev/sda6  459732992 500117503  40384512  19.3G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x93560dfd

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 488394751 488392704 232.9G 83 Linux
```

Based on the above I assume I should do it on:

```
/dev/sda4    1083392 457779199 456695808 217.8G Microsoft basic data
```

Meaning I would run this command:

```
sudo install-mbr -i n -p D -t 0 /dev/sda4
```

Is that correct?

Comment: You don't need to enter any license serial to start from a Windows disk to fix startup issues. Just need a Windows ISO image of same version, make bootable disk using a thumbdrive, then you can start troubleshooting. Less chances of damaging partition table and losing all files. Recovery disk is needed for restoring the OS in its entirety, which might also have a copy of your factory activated OS.

Comment: Currently I cannot boot windows at all so am trying  to fix that from ubuntu. In windows 8 you only have access to recovery if you restart from windows

Answer (score 0):

You have a EFI boot, I think mbr will not work for you.

Can you choose Win8 boot option from GRUB?, if not try to use `Grub Customizer` to fix any boot issues.
Install it

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`

(Or from `Ubuntu Software`)

First run and you can see the win8 boot entry, press Save and reboot your machine.
In GRUB menu selected Windows boot option and press and hold `SHIFT` key before press ENTER, you will enter to RECOVERY mode and then you can choose repair boot issues for windows.